# How to show full column content in a Spark Dataframe?

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, spark-csv, output-formatting

I am using spark-csv to load data into a DataFrame. I want to do a simple query and display the content:

```
val df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").load("my.csv")
df.registerTempTable("tasks")
results = sqlContext.sql("select col from tasks");
results.show()
```

The col seems truncated:

```
scala> results.show();
+--------------------+
|                 col|
+--------------------+
|2015-11-16 07:15:...|
|2015-11-16 07:15:...|
|2015-11-16 07:15:...|
|2015-11-16 07:15:...|
|2015-11-16 07:15:...|
|2015-11-16 07:15:...|
|2015-11-16 07:15:...|
|2015-11-16 07:15:...|
|2015-11-16 07:15:...|
|2015-11-16 07:15:...|
|2015-11-16 07:15:...|
|2015-11-16 07:15:...|
|2015-11-16 07:15:...|
|2015-11-16 07:15:...|
|2015-11-16 07:15:...|
|2015-11-06 07:15:...|
|2015-11-16 07:15:...|
|2015-11-16 07:21:...|
|2015-11-16 07:21:...|
|2015-11-16 07:21:...|
+--------------------+
```

How do I show the full content of the column?

Answer (score 562, accepted):

`results.show(20, false)` will not truncate. Check the [source](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/d83c2f9f0b08d6d5d369d9fae04cdb15448e7f0d/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.scala#L395)

`20` is the default number of rows displayed when `show()` is called without any arguments.

Comment: Not OP but this is indeed the right answer : Minor correction, boolean should be False, not false.

Comment: It would be "False" in python, but "false" in scala/java

Comment: it's false (not False) in spark-shell

Comment: the equivalent for writing to stream in console mode is `dataFrame.writeStream.outputMode("append").format("console").option("truncate", "false").start()`

Comment: what is so special about 20? Why 20?

Comment: OP asked how not to truncate the columns, so @TomTom101 gave them the equivalent of `df.show()` (20 rows per default) that does not truncate the columns. I.e. `df.show(20, false)`

Comment: Use dataframe_name.show(truncate = False)

Comment: FYI: there is another interesting option for show which is to show "vertically" -- the third optional argument: n=20, truncate=True, vertical=False. It's sometimes easier to read the data in this format.

Comment: any alternative for %%sql spark magic for this ?

Answer (score 68):

If you put `results.show(false)` , results will not be truncated

Comment: I imagine that [the comment on TomTom101's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3435649/xv70) about `false` applies here, too.

Comment: @Narendra Parmar the syntax should be `results.show(20, False)`. The one you have mentioned will give error.

Comment: @ Jai Prakash , i have given this answer for scala and you are talking about python,

Comment: @NarendraParmar sorry you are correct. In `scala` both the options are valid. `results.show(false)` and `results.show(20, false)`

Comment: @JaiPrakash -- in ASA, "false" has to have a capital f:  "False" is ok, but "false" gives an error.

Answer (score 41):

Below code would help to view all rows without truncation in each column

```
df.show(df.count(), False)
```

Comment: same questio i asked the prior answerer: does this cause `df` to be collected twice?

Comment: @javadba yes, I think count() will go through df once, and show() will collect df twice.

Comment: As an alternative, you could give a very large number as the first parameter instead of `df.count()` in order to save on the requirement to persist. For example, if the row count of df is 1000, you could do `df.show(1000000, false)` and it will work. Tried the following and it worked: `scala> println(df.count)
res2: Long = 987
scala> df.show(990)`

Answer (score 23):

The other solutions are good. If these are your goals:

1. No truncation of columns,
2. No loss of rows,
3. Fast and
4. Efficient

These two lines are useful ...

```
    df.persist
    df.show(df.count, false) // in Scala or 'False' in Python
```

By persisting, the 2 executor actions, count and show, are faster & more efficient when using `persist` or `cache` to maintain the interim underlying dataframe structure within the executors. See more about [persist and cache](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-rdd-caching.html).

Comment: Very nice.  Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

`results.show(20, False)` or `results.show(20, false)`
depending on whether you are running it on Java/Scala/Python

Answer (score 11):

In **Pyspark** we can use

df.show(truncate=False) this will display the full content of the columns without truncation.

df.show(5,truncate=False) this will display the full content of the first five rows.

Answer (score 9):

The following answer applies to a Spark Streaming application.

By setting the "truncate" option to false, you can tell the output sink to display the full column.

```
val query = out.writeStream
          .outputMode(OutputMode.Update())
          .format("console")
          .option("truncate", false)
          .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("5 seconds"))
          .start()
```

Answer (score 6):

In Spark Pythonic way, remember:

- if you have to display data from a dataframe, use `show(truncate=False)` method.
- else if you have to display data from a Stream dataframe view (Structured Streaming), use the `writeStream.format("console").option("truncate", False).start()` methods with option.

Hope it could helps someone.

Answer (score 4):

Within [Databricks](https://databricks.com/try-databricks) you can visualize the dataframe in a tabular format. With the command:

```
display(results)
```

It will look like

[image]

Comment: how with display() show only, for example, first 5 rows?

Answer (score 4):

In c#  `Option("truncate", false)` does not truncate data in the output.

```
StreamingQuery query = spark
                    .Sql("SELECT * FROM Messages")
                    .WriteStream()
                    .OutputMode("append")
                    .Format("console")
                    .Option("truncate", false)
                    .Start();
```

Answer (score 4):

Try
df.show(20,False)

Notice that if you do not specify the number of rows you want to show, it will show
20 rows but will execute all your dataframe which will take more time !

Answer (score 3):

try this command     :

```
df.show(df.count())
```

Comment: Try this:
df.show(some no) will work but df.show(df.count()) will not work df.count gives output type long which is not accepted by df.show() as it accept integer type.

Comment: Example use df.show(2000). It will retrieve 2000 rows

Comment: does this cause `df` to be collected twice?

Answer (score 3):

`results.show(false)` will show you the full column content.

Show method by default limit to 20, and adding a number before `false` will show more rows.

Answer (score 3):

`results.show(20,false)` did the trick for me in Scala.

Answer (score 3):

Tried this in pyspark

```
df.show(truncate=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

**PYSPARK**

In the below code, `df` is the name of dataframe. 1st parameter is to show all rows in the dataframe dynamically rather than hardcoding a numeric value. The 2nd parameter will take care of displaying full column contents since the value is set as `False`.

```
df.show(df.count(),False)
```

[image]

**SCALA**

In the below code, `df` is the name of dataframe. 1st parameter is to show all rows in the dataframe dynamically rather than hardcoding a numeric value. The 2nd parameter will take care of displaying full column contents since the value is set as `false`.

```
df.show(df.count().toInt,false)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this in scala:

```
df.show(df.count.toInt, false)
```

The show method accepts an integer and a Boolean value but df.count returns Long...so type casting is required