# Timestamp field is losing precision when queried using spark-sql

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

The **timestamp field** is losing precision when querying the same table from `Hive Metastore` using **Spark SQL**.

My table description goes like this :

```
col_name  data_type  comment
id          bigint    null
name        string    null
joined_time timestamp null
```

Using Hive QL, I get `joined_time` values in milliseconds precision.
Hive QL results:

```
select * from employees;

1   foo 2016-07-04 02:12:10.0
2   bar 2016-07-04 02:12:10.0
```

While using `spark-sql`, I lose precision, upto minutes. e.g :

```
val result = sqlContext.sql("select * from employees")
result.show()

1  foo 2016-07-04 02:12:...
2  bar 2016-07-04 02:12:...
```

Comment: It's not loosing precision. I has just truncated the display. you can display it with result.show(false)

Comment: @eliasah there isn't a show method with boolean argument

Comment: It says  error: type mismatch required int

Comment: which version of spark are you ? I used that everyday :)

Comment: I'm using spark 1.3.0 in cloudera-quick-start-vm-5.4.2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135383/discussion-between-narush-and-eliasah).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not loosing precision. It has just truncated the display.

Since **Spark 1.6**, you can display it with `result.show(false)`

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset

```
val df = Seq((1,2),(2,4)).toDF("x","y")
df.show(false)
// +---+---+
// |x  |y  |
// +---+---+
// |1  |2  |
// |2  |4  |
// +---+---+
```

Now with timestamps :

```
sqlContext.sql("select current_timestamp()").show
// +--------------------+
// |                 _c0|
// +--------------------+
// |2017-02-10 14:40:...|
// +--------------------+

sqlContext.sql("select current_timestamp()").show(false)
// +-----------------------+
// |_c0                    |
// +-----------------------+
// |2017-02-10 14:40:14.038|
// +-----------------------+
```

Comment: In the case of Spark DataFrames, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33742895/how-to-show-full-column-content-in-a-spark-dataframe