# How to explode map type in pyspark dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have a dataframe

```
import os, sys
import json, time, random, string, requests
import pyodbc 
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode, col, from_json, lit
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *
...
df = data.withColumn("dev_serial", col("data.dev_serial")) \
   .withColumn("dev_property", from_json(col("data.dev_property"), MapType(StringType(), StringType())) )\
   .drop("data")
df.show(truncate=False)
df.printSchema()
```

and This result is here

[image]

I want to explode dev_property(column)

```
dev_serial / use_event / item / ...
value1 / value2 / value3 /value4
.
.
.
```

How to explode?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show full column content in a Spark Dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33742895/how-to-show-full-column-content-in-a-spark-dataframe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you want to explode the dev_property column into two columns, this script would be helpful:

```
df2 = df.select(df.dev_serial, explode(df.dev_property))
df2.printSchema()
df2.show()
```

[Read more](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-explode-array-and-map-columns-to-rows/) about how explode works on Array and Map types.

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.
From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_

Comment: Thanks, but This results is not complete me.
I want to this

columns : dev_serial / key1 / key 2 / key3 ...
values : 1401 / value1 / value2 / value3

but your solution's result is

columns : dev_serial / key / value 
values : 1401 / key1 / value1 ...

Are you have another solution ?

Comment: Thanks to the site you told me, I solved the problem. Thank you!!!

Comment: @KIMJAEMIN, good to know. You can add the solution that worked for you.